# Onsen 1.3.14 android backbutton exit application instead of calling navi.popPage()

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, onsen-ui

Im using Onsen 1.3.14. From what I've read, I thought android backbutton should be calling navi.popPage() by default, but instead my application always exited.

I also have tried using this

[Workaround using $rootScope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XpRL.png)

but it still wont work.

Is it a bug? Is there a workaround to make android backbutton not exiting the app?

Thanks.

Regards

Comment: navi.popPage() only works on navigator subpages, which when you are already on top pages (where `<ons-navigator>` declared, you cannot popPage anymore, as the subpages stack already empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true that the android backbutton should be calling `navi.popPage()`. What if, for example, there is a sliding menu instead of a navigator?

If you want to implement a `popPage`, you can write something like this:

```js
document.addEventListener("backbutton",onBackButtonPressed, false);

function onBackButtonPressed(){
        var element = document.querySelector("ons-navigator");
        element.popPage();
}
```

If you want to learn more about how to handle the android backbutton in Onsen UI, you can take a look at the official documentation:

https://onsen.io/guide/overview.html#HandlingBackButton

Comment: Hi Andi, thanks for the reply.

I've tried your example above, but unfortunately the app still exited when I pressed the Android backbutton. Do you think there might be other ways to solve this problem? Its starting to give me a headache.

Cheers

Comment: I've also tried the code in the link you gave me, but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do first define a module

```
 var module = ons.bootstrap('my-app', ['onsen']);
```

Then you can initiate ons-navigator tag above your ons-page tag

```
<ons-navigator title="Navigator" var="myNavigator">
```

And then you can simply add the back button in your toolbar

```
<ons-toolbar>
    <div class="left">
        <ons-back-button fixed-width="false" style="font-size: 26px; vertical-align: -4px">Back</ons-back-button>
    </div>
    </ons-toolbar>
```